# I am trying to print 5 random cards from a deck of 52 and then sort the 5 cards ascending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

the output when i run it with the sorted array is 10 of suit, 10 of suit, 10 of suit, 10 of suit, 2 of suit. but when i take off the Array.sort it will generate the 5 random cards but not in ascending order. any idea of why this is happen?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Proj4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int WID = 859653508;
        int lastDigits = WID % 10000;
        int count = 0;
        final int DIAMONDS = 0, HEARTS = 1, CLUBS = 2, SPADES = 3;
        final int JACK = 11, QUEEN = 12, KING = 13, ACE = 14;
        String passWord = "CIS200$Spr20";
        String L = "Deaton";
        String username = "Deat3508";
        String[] suits = new String[]{"Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades"};
        String[] values = new String[]{"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King","Ace"};



        int t = suits.length * values.length;
        String[] deck = new String[t];
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < suits.length; j++){
                deck[suits.length*i+j] = values[i] + " of " + suits[j];
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
            int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (t-i));
            String temp = deck[r];
            deck[r] = deck[i];
            deck[i] = temp;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Arrays.sort(values);
            System.out.println(deck[i]);
        }

            if(deck[1].equals(deck[2]) && deck[2].equals(deck[3]) && deck[3].equals(deck[4]))
                System.out.print("Flush");
            if(deck[1].equals(deck[2+1]) && deck[2].equals(deck[2+1]) && deck[3].equals(deck[3+1]) &&
            deck[4].equals(deck[4+1]) && deck[5].equals(deck[5+1]))
                System.out.print("Straight");
            if(deck[1].equals(deck[2]) && deck[2].equals(deck[3]) || deck[3].equals(deck[4])
    && deck[4].equals(deck[5]))
                System.out.println("Three of a Kind");


    }
}
```

Comment: You are sorting in a loop, and (to your problem) you are sorting **`values`** (not **`deck`**) with `Arrays.sort(values);`

Comment: This looks like homework (?) — are you allowed to use your own classes yet? A better representation for a card in a deck is to have a `public class Card` which contains a suit and a value, rather than just Strings. You would want `public class Card implements Comparable` and you'd write methods for `equals` and `compareTo` which together allow Cards to be sorted.

Comment: yes it is we can not use other classes all has to be in one class

Comment: One thing ... your `Arrays.sort` is sorting _Strings_, not Values. As a String `1` comes before `2` even if it's the `10` part of "10 of suit", which is why the 10s come before the 2s. You are also calling `.sort()` 5 times in the loop. That won't change the outcome, but you should only be sorting once, _before_ the loop printing 5 cards. You also need to take your 5 chosen cards, put them in a _different_ array, and sort _that_. You randomize `deck` and want the first 5 random cards, but then you sort `deck`, undoing the randomness.

Answer (score -1):

Taking 5 random card from a random deck of 52 can be accomplished by taking the second to sixth (index 1 to 5 as in your code) cards which is as random as taking any 5 cards. Because of your sorting error, as pointed out by others, you still accomplish what you set out to do by taking array[1 ... 5]

Now why sort deck when you shuffled it a few lines above? Note that arrays are 0 based.

All you have to do is copy the 5 cards in a new array of size 5 and sort that array. Now you have to make sure the sorting is done in your expected order. Stings are sorted by unicode lexical order. You might want to rename your cards "1 (Ace), 11 (Jack) so that the order is ok.

Comment: so we have to shuffle 5 random cards and then display what kind of poker hand it is and i was told to do that when you sort the cards drawn in ascending order